# android how to get last movement

Tags: android, events, motion

For example, I move my finger down the screen and then back up. So, this should count as two drags, the last movement before I paused for a split second and after that when I moved back up. I basically count every time I make a new movement without lifting my finger off the screen. So, how do I get the last movement before I stop movement without lifting my finger?

I'm using motion event. Here is the code in action_move:

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

        posY = event.getY();
        posX = event.getX();
        diffPosY = posY - oldY;
        diffPosX = posX - oldX;

        if (checkMovement(posY, oldY)){
            if (diffPosY > 0 || diffPosY < 0){

                count +=1;


                }
        } 


    public boolean checkMovement(float posY, float oldY) {

    int newY = Math.round(posY);
    double distance = Math.abs(newY - oldY);

    oldY = newY;

    if (distance < 25)


    return false;

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple like this

```
private int mLastMovY = 0;

case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

        posY = event.getY();
        posX = event.getX();
        diffPosY = posY - oldY;
        diffPosX = posX - oldX;
        if(diffPosY > 0){//up
            if(mLastMovY != 0){//if have any drag down before, the value will != 0
                count +=1; 
                //could save value of mLastMovY before reset it, this is last position when user drag down
                mLastMovY = 0;//reset it to avoid 'count' be increased
            }
        }
        else{//down
            mLastMovY = posY;//drag down will assign value to mLastMovY
        }
```

Comment: Thank you, but when I move up and down why does it count more than two moves e.g. 10 or 14 or more?

Comment: Thank you for the answer, would it be ok if you explained the code with comments - from "mLastMovY = 0" onwards please?